# application hangs when using TextWatcher

Tags: android, kotlin

**when the emulator is turned on, it crashes when trying to change parameters*

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

                if (editText.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    status.text = "error"
                }
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                try { editText2.setText("${editText.toString().toFloat() * 39370}")
                }
                catch (f: NumberFormatException){}
                    status.text = "error"
                editText2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                    override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}

                    override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                        try {
                            editText.setText("${editText2.text.toString().toFloat() / 39370}")
                        }catch (e: NumberFormatException){
                            status.text = "error"
                        }
                    }

                    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                        if(editText2.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                            status.text = "error"
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
        })
    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
    2021-08-07 15:14:31.145 552-10994/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.company.myapplication (com.example.company.myapplication/.MainActivity)
    PID: 10958
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (1a128e0 com.example.company.myapplication/com.example.company.myapplication.MainActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5000ms for KeyEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00000301, displayId=-1, action=DOWN, flags=0x00000008, keyCode=67, scanCode=14, metaState=0x00000000, repeatCount=0), policyFlags=0x62000000)
    Parent: com.example.company.myapplication/.MainActivity
    Load: 0.35 / 0.29 / 0.28
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=5379069
    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=859915
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    
    CPU usage from 53152ms to 0ms ago (2021-08-07 12:13:35.741 to 2021-08-07 12:14:28.893):
      2.7% 308/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.1-service.sim: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
      2.3% 384/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 42 minor
      2.2% 330/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.3-service: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
      2.2% 552/system_server: 0.3% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 4538 minor
      1.1% 9469/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.1% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 3447 minor
      0.7% 813/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 87 minor
      0.5% 364/android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.1% 483/llkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.3% 1532/com.google.android.gms: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3361 minor
      0.3% 404/adbd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 286 minor
      0.2% 305/android.hardware.audio.service.ranchu: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 3 minor
      0.2% 169/logd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 6 minor
      0.1% 329/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@3.0-service: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 388/audioserver: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3 minor
      0.1% 1261/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 482 minor
      0.1% 3154/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2413 minor 2 major
      0.1% 10/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 392/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1156/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 58 minor
      0% 26/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 8960/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 16/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 421/traced_probes: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
      0% 10421/kworker/u8:0-cfg80211: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 10627/kworker/u8:1-phy0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 171/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1077/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 46 minor
      0% 1/init: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 9/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 21/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 170/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 294/statsd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
      0% 296/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 168 minor
      0% 370/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 443/iorapd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
      0% 454/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1018/android.hardware.gnss@2.0-service.ranchu: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1056/com.android.networkstack.process: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 24 minor
      0% 7971/kworker/3:0-mm_percpu_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 10958/com.example.company.myapplication: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 10983/kworker/0:2-mm_percpu_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
    8.5% TOTAL: 4.1% user + 4.3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
    CPU usage from 20ms to 384ms later (2021-08-07 12:14:28.913 to 2021-08-07 12:14:29.276):
      124% 10958/com.example.company.myapplication: 102% user + 22% kernel / faults: 1789 minor
        97% 10958/y.myapplication: 97% user + 0% kernel
        26% 10972/HeapTaskDaemon: 4.4% user + 22% kernel
      33% 552/system_server: 0% user + 33% kernel / faults: 281 minor
        29% 10994/AnrConsumer: 0% user + 29% kernel
      3.1% 308/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.1-service.sim: 0% user + 3.1% kernel
        3.1% 1328/bluetooth@1.1-s: 0% user + 3.1% kernel
2021-08-07 15:14:31.145 552-10994/system_process E/ActivityManager:   3.1% 330/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.3-service: 0% user + 3.1% kernel
        3.1% 359/: 0% user + 3.1% kernel
    44% TOTAL: 23% user + 21% kernel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an Application Not Responding crash, which means your code is blocking and taking too long to do something. It can be a sign you're in a neverending loop, which is probably what's happening here.

You're setting two `TextWatcher`s here, one on `editText` and one on `editText2`. The `onTextChanged` callback fires when... the text changes obviously! When the text changes in `editText`, that method runs and does this:

```
editText2.setText("${editText.toString().toFloat() * 39370}")
```

It's setting the text on `editText2`. So **its** `onTextChanged` fires, and does this:

```
editText.setText("${editText2.text.toString().toFloat() / 39370}")
```

See the problem here? Each time the text changes in one, it changes the text in the other, which changes the text in the first one again, which changes... you get the idea. It never ends, and your app hangs

Answer (score 1):

```
   edittask.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

        }
        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            val inputText: String = edittask.getText().toString()
            if (inputText.length > 0) {
                colordot.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"))
            } else {
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                addtask.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.gray)))
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            val inputText: String = edittask.getText().toString()
            if (inputText.length > 0) {
                addtask.setEnabled(true)
                addtask.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.bg)))
            } else {
                addtask.setEnabled(false)
            }
        }
    })
```